# Does an Amazon EC2 Reserved Instance with SQL server include an SQL licence?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql

I was wondering if in the Amazon EC2 Reserved Instance with SQL server, the extra cost was just for the ability to run an SQL server. Or if this included a license and SQL.

It would be a real bummer if after paying for the Reserved Instance, I also had to purchase a very costly license to use SQL.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the licensing costs are built into the hourly price.

http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

> If Microsoft chooses to increase the license fees that it charges for Windows or SQL Server Standard, we may correspondingly increase the per-hour usage rate for previously purchased Reserved Instances with Windows or Windows and SQL Server.